# I'm getting many errors compiling with g++

Tags: linux, g++

I need to create an application which can be ran on Windows and Linux, use SQLite, and written in C++. I'm learning how to use SQLite with C++ so, I made a simple SQLite wrapper that executes queries and you can retrieve the results.

I wrote this application using Visual Studio 2010, but I didn't use any .NET libraries or anything that could be related to Windows.

The program compiles on Windows and it works, but when I take it over to linux everything compiles except the SQLite library; I'm running arch and with gcc v4.7.2.

To include the SQLite library, I went to the SQLite download page and downloaded [Source Code](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). I extracted `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` and included `sqlite3.h` in my class.

This was the command which I gave to compile the code: `g++ sqlite3.c DatabaseConnection.cpp SQLiteExample.cpp`

Since there is a bit of code and lot of errors, I'm just going to link them here:

- [All the errors](http://pastebin.com/7cDdjh1g)
- [A link to my code](https://github.com/samwell/SQLiteExample)

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to install your distributions development package of SQLite (named something like `libsqlite3-dev` or similar), and then use that?

Comment: `sqlite3.c` seems to be written in C, not C++. Did you try compiling it with a C compiler (like gcc)? C++ is more strict about many things so the code may be invalid C++.

Comment: Your question is not self-contained, since it depends upon external links (which will become stale with time).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would, but the environment I'm in doesn't allow users to install packages, and the admins are very adamant on not installing it.

Comment: @honk so should I compile `sqlite3.c` separately with `gcc`, then use `g++` to compile my program?

Comment: @samwell: Exactly, see e.g. perreal's answer which does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Makefile:

```
FLAGS=-Wall -Werror
LIBS=-lpthread -ldl
all: sqlite3.o
        g++ $(FLAGS) sqlite3.o DatabaseConnection.cpp SQLiteExample.cpp $(LIBS)  

sqlite3.o:
        gcc $(FLAGS) sqlite3.c -c
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked. I added the make file to the repository.

Comment: You should at least pass `-Wall -g` to both `g++` and `gcc`